# An elementary question about Gaussian primes

Tags: nt.number-theory

Suppose we consider primes of the form $p = 1 \text { mod } 4$, so that $p = a^2 + b^2$, $a$ and $b$ being integers. Considering only the first quadrant, all $(a,b)$ pairs will be of the form (odd,even) or (even,odd).

Now if we consider $q = (a + n)^2 + (b + n)^2 = p + 2na + 2nb + 2n^2$, $n$ an integer, then $q = 1 \text { mod } 4$.

$1 \text { mod } 4$ as an arithmetic progression contains an infinite number of primes, and while every $q$ may not turn out to be a prime, one would still expect an infinite number of prime pairs $(p,q)$.

Has any work been done related to this? My original motivation was that this could give very close Gaussian primes, differing by a distance of just $n\sqrt2$, when $n$ is small.

**Update**: I came across a recent paper ([Bounded gaps between Gaussian primes](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~akshaa/gaussian.pdf)) where instead of $(a + n,b + n)$, the author considers $(a + n,b + m)$, with $(n,m)$ either $\text (odd,odd)$ or $\text (even,even)$, and then proves it for the case $(0,m)$, $m>=246$.

Comment: Check out [Bunyakovsky conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture).

Comment: This is a particular case of a natural conjecture that would generalize Dirichlet's theorem to the Gaussian integers, but this generalization is not known. I doubt this particular case is known. It is a famous open problem whether there are infinitely many primes in another arithmetic progression, $n+i$, or equivalently, infinitely many primes in the integers of the form $n^2+1$.

Comment: I am pretty sure that Bunyakovsky conjecture is open for any specific nonlinear polynomial. And probably (less sure here) it is not even proved that there exists a nonlinear polynomial for which it holds.

Comment: Friedlander and Iwaniec's paper (http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9811185.pdf) mentions that the problem in one variable is generally more difficult than that in two. So it's possible this problem is more tractable than Bunyakovsky's.

Comment: @valar123 this question is equivalent to the specific case of Bunyakovsky conjecture, is not it?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Well, the Wikipedia page on the conjecture mentions that it applies to single variable polynomials, while in this case (a,b,n) are all variable, so maybe it can be interpreted as a multivariable generalization. Moreover, some multivariable polynomials are already known to contain infinite number of primes (eg. $a^2 + b^2$ or $a^2 + b^4$), while in case of single variables, since even $a^2 + 1$ isn't resolved yet, I guess the multivariable case is thought to be easier to handle.

Comment: I thought that you fix $a,b$ and vary only $n$. If not, what exactly is your question?

Comment: I was thinking more in terms of a process. Suppose I take a random 1mod4 prime, decompose it as a sum of squares, getting a Gaussian prime, then I perturb the GP by a small n, and calculate the new sum of squares ending with a 1mod4 prime candidate. If the prime candidate then often turns out to be prime, then I often get a close pair of Gaussian primes. Since the original 1mod4 prime can be taken randomly, the associated Gaussian prime is also variable.

Comment: @FedorPetrov the following scenario may help explain it more clearly. Suppose the Bunyakovsky conjecture is false, and so for any given 1mod4 prime p, I run the "algorithm" above for all n, get a list of 1mod4 candidates q, of which only a finite number turn out to be prime. But if there an infinite number of p, each with finite such q, (and at least some of the q generated with small n), the first question would still be satisfied. The conjecture seems stricter than the question requires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An infinite number of primes on a ray of slope $45^{\circ}$ would not imply close Gaussian primes any more than ordinary primes $0^{\circ}.$ I didn't read  the paper you link, but $246$ is the current record for gaps between ordinary primes. You might enjoy reading about [Guassian moats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_moat).

Comment: The result for ordinary primes by Maynard, Tao and Polymath was in 2013-14, while the paper I linked seems to be very recent (Nov 2015). I found the link on the Polymath project page (http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Bounded_gaps_between_primes), so it seems credible. The author has adapted the original machinery for Gaussian primes. Maybe the first question doesn't have a elementary solution. I read about Gaussian moats, and the subject is indeed fascinating :)